# Задача с массивом объектов

Tags: javascript, функции, объекты

Дан массив объектов

```
const objectArray = [

firstObject = {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 32
},

secondObject = {
  name: "Caroline",
  age: 1
},

thirdObject = {
  name: "Sam",
  age: 35
},
];
```

Нужно написать функцию,которая принимает параметром строку, и возвращает новый массив объектов,в имени которых эта строка содержится.Например строка "Sam".Должно вернуть массив с 1 и 3 объектами.

```
const name = "Sam";
const makeAgeDiscrimArray = (name) => {
  const result = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < objectArray.length; i++) {
  if ((objectArray[i].name == name)) {
      result.push(objectArray[i])} // <= objectArray[i]
  }
};

alert(makeAgeDiscrimArray(objectArray));
```

У меня ничего не получилось

Comment: Ваша задача решается через функцию `Array.filter()`

Comment: В вашем коде нужно исправить два момента: вызывать функцию с правильным параметром `console.log(makeAgeDiscrimArray(name));` и добавить в конце функции `return result;`. Да и массив лучше передавать в параметре. Но вам уже подсказали более простое решение)

Answer (score 1):

```js
const objectArray = [
  firstObject = {
      name: "Sam",
      age: 32
  },

  secondObject = {
    name: "Caroline",
    age: 1
  },

  thirdObject = {
    name: "Sam",
    age: 35
  },
];

const filtered = (name) => {
  return objectArray.filter((item) => {
    return item.name === name;
  });
}

console.log(filtered('Sam'));
```